# Best way to return bidirectional GRPC method. .NET 5 C#

Tags: c#, grpc, .net-5, kestrel, grpc-c#

```
public override async Task DO(IAsyncStreamReader<Request> requestStream, IServerStreamWriter<Response> responseStream, ServerCallContext context)
{
    try
    {
        while (!context.CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested && await requestStream.MoveNext())
        {
            var message = requestStream.Current;

            switch (message.RequestUnionCase)
            {
                    case RequestUnionOneofCase.InitMessage:
                        isInitMessageDone = true;

                        var status = new Response
                        {
                            Status = new Status
                            {
                                Code = 100,
                                Details = "Continue",
                            }
                        };

                        await responseStream.WriteAsync(status);

                        break;
                    case RequestUnionOneofCase.C: break;
                    case RequestUnionOneofCase.A:
                        isDone = true;
                        break;

                    case RequestUnionOneofCase.None: break;
                    default: break;
                }
            }               

            if (isInitMessageDone && isDone)
            {
                var status = new Response
                {
                    Status = new Status
                    {
                        Code = 200,
                        Details = "Success"
                    }
                };

                await responseStream.WriteAsync(status);

                Response finalResult = await this._responseMessageHandler.ProcessResultAsync();
                finalResult.Result.ResultType = EnumResultType.Final;
                await responseStream.WriteAsync(finalResult);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            
        }
}
```

1. What is the issue in the above code regarding gracefully return the method.
2. How to write stream when client have done complete sending request stream

I am getting following exception when running 100 users multiple times.

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException at
> Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions+d__14`1.MoveNext

3. The following are the Kestrel setting I used to get the same error when had all default settings

   ```
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentConnections = 10000;
    options.Limits.MaxConcurrentUpgradedConnections = 10000;
    options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
    options.Limits.Http2.MaxStreamsPerConnection = 10000;
   ```

Error:

> SERVER
> problemId Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions+d__14`1.MoveNext type Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException assembly Grpc.AspNetCore.Server, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad method Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions+<ReadStreamMessageAsync>d__14`1.MoveNext
> outerType System.IO.IOException
> outerMessage The request stream was aborted.
> outerAssembly System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e
> outerMethod System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw
> innermostType Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException
> innermostMessage The HTTP/2 connection faulted.

{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":0,"line":0}1
{"assembly":"System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51","method":"System.IO.Pipelines.PipeCompletion.ThrowLatchedException","level":1,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51","method":"System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult","level":2,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.IO.Pipelines, Version=5.0.0.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51","method":"System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult","level":3,"line":0}
{"assembly":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60","method":"Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody+d__9.MoveNext","level":4,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":5,"line":0}
{"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":6,"line":0}
{"assembly":"Grpc.AspNetCore.Server, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad","method":"Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions+d__14`1.MoveNext","level":7,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":8,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":9,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification","level":10,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1.get_Result","level":11,"line":0}
{"assembly":"Grpc.AspNetCore.Server, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d754f35622e28bad","method":"Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.HttpContextStreamReader`1+<<MoveNext>g__MoveNextAsync|9_0>d.MoveNext","level":12,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw","level":13,"line":0} {"assembly":"System.Private.CoreLib, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e","method":"System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess","level":14,"line":0} {Category} {SessionId} {MessageId} Exception during Responder Reader Task, Exception message: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.  IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted. ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadAtLeastAsync(Stream stream, Memory`1 buffer, Int32 minReadBytes)
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.EnsureIncomingBytesAsync(Int32 minReadBytes)   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(Boolean initialFrame)
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryEnsureHeaders()
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"),
Exception stacktrace:
at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

CLIENT
Exception during Responder Reader Task, Exception message: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="Error starting gRPC call. HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request.
IOException: The request was aborted. IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.", DebugException="System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error occurred while sending the request. ---> System.IO.IOException: The request was aborted. ---> System.IO.IOException: The response ended prematurely, with at least 9 additional bytes expected.
at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadAtLeastAsync(Stream stream, Memory`1 buffer, Int32 minReadBytes)    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.EnsureIncomingBytesAsync(Int32 minReadBytes)   at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ReadFrameAsync(Boolean initialFrame)    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.ProcessIncomingFramesAsync()   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.CheckResponseBodyState()    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.TryEnsureHeaders()    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.Http2Stream.ReadResponseHeadersAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Net.Http.Http2Connection.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionPool.SendWithRetryAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Boolean doRequestAuth, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.RedirectHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at System.Net.Http.DiagnosticsHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)    at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.GrpcCall`2.RunCall(HttpRequestMessage request, Nullable`1 timeout)"),  Exception stacktrace:     at Grpc.Net.Client.Internal.HttpContentClientStreamReader`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: You have two network layers 1) GRPC which is the connection 2) The application layer.  Normal HTTP closes the connection after a request/response.  GRPC keeps connection open so multiple messages can be sent on same connection.  Each Request/Response is a HTML formatted message which has a root open and close tag.  So the receiving side of connection knows when each request/response is completed.  So you have to make sure your messages are a valid HTML message.

Comment: @jdweng gRPC messages do not need to be HTML in any way - indeed, most of the time, gRPC uses protobuf - so: messages cannot even remotely be HTML. I'm not sure what point you're trying to make about HTTP/HTML here. Under the hood, gRPC streaming is implemented using separate data frames in HTTP/2.

Comment: @Atulya 1) "What is the issue in the above code regarding gracefully return the method." - can you clarify what you mean here? what problem are you seeing? 2) and... was the client connection aborted? that can absolutely happen

Comment: @MarcGravell : Messages have to be properly terminated.  The messages have a header and can contain html body.  Also it is a master slave communications when one request is sent and then a response is returned before another request is sent.

Comment: @jdweng message framing is part of the gRPC library; all the *consumer* needs to do is access the context correctly, for example by awaiting writes so you don't end up with concurrency problems - all of which is being done correctly in the code in the question; and no, individual gRPC payloads in a duplex stream don't have html bodies as such. It isn't clear to me what you're suggesting OP should do differently here.

Comment: @MarcGravell Let me explain in details: I have one mentioned above bidirectional service which have following request type in sequence: 1. Init, 2. audio (22 chunks) and client do CompleteAsync() and then the service returns the final result.
ISSUE: when I go beyond 100-200 connections I see two common exception in both client and server both are at while reading and writing streams. "So I was assuming I am not able to return the service graceful"  I was wondering If I can write stream after moveNext while loop is over. I have mentioned the server exception.

Comment: @Atulya the inbound and outbound pipes are largely unrelated, but yes: you should still be able to write a response after the request loop has closed; if you think about it, that is the *expected* use-case most of the time (in a request/response scenario, masquerading as full duplex)

Comment: @MarcGravell so it clear that both read and write are independent. but still 1) do not know the reason behind the exception and 2) Is my while loop handling is the ideal way to handle cancellation/ CompleteAsync()?, will this works in multithread? 
I have changes the default configuration will that helps in removing the exception.

Comment: @Atulya the exception suggests that the client aborted, most likely due to a timeout condition - that's not uncommon on a busy and/or overloaded server; re multi-threading: the send and receive are independent, but you should not attempt to send from two flows concurrently or receive from two flows concurrently - very similar to `NetworkStream` or `Socket`, basically

Comment: @MarcGravell could you please point me to some awesome article which show the graceful handling of complete steam/ cancellation token/ rpc exception handling in bi-direction service(Server Side).

Comment: @Atulya I don't have such a link; feel free to write it!